# Отправка json запроса на Corezoid

Tags: jquery

Изучаю мануал [Corezoid](https://doc.corezoid.com/ru/interface/tasks/direct_url.html) и там показано, как через Postman отправить запрос. Через Postman эта задача выполняется успешно, но не получается отправить данных запрос через jQuery при загрузке страницы, ошибка 405

Код jq

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://www.corezoid.com/api/1/json/public/260418/75e18e414015199791af926579e7b6faed2b9f5e',
        type:"POST",
        data:{"link": "http://myhref/online/", "text": "testText","title": "testTitle"},
        contentType:"application/json;",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(){
             ...
        }
    })
})
```

Получаю ошибку 
`OPTIONS https://www.corezoid.com/api/1/json/public/260418/75e18e414015199791af926579e7b6faed2b9f5e 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.corezoid.com/api/1/json/public/260418/75e18e414015199791af926579e7b6faed2b9f5e. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myhref' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Comment: понял, что нужно добавить в конструкцию jq код `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");`, но не понимаю как добавить

Comment: не в jq надо это добавлять, а на сервере.